# Add Basemap showing blank window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-online-basemaps

I tried adding a base map with Adding Base map, but the window where types of base maps are selected is blank.

I tried clearing the display cache but to no avail.
I was able to add base maps before with no problems, but recently it just stopped working. 
I didn't update anything prior to this.

How can I fix this, so I can add base maps again?

[image: Screen shot of the blank window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try (from a GeoNet [post](https://community.esri.com/message/39646#comment-221569))

> Open internet explorer and got to the tools, click on internet options, then Connections then LAN Settings. Uncheck the option that says Automatically detect settings. Basically the problem was that the basemap was searching for the host site through all my local networks and unchecking this option bypasses that.