# Can't add basemap (button is greyed out) in ArcGIS Pro 3

Tags: arcgis-pro, basemap

I'm following an online course to learn the fundamentals of GIS.
We got a ArcGIS Pro 3 to use.
Now the course material is all about using ArcMap, which is posing a small problem, but so far I have managed to perform everything in the course.

But now I need to add a basemap to an existing project.
Only thing is that the Add Basemap button in the Layer section is greyed out.
I've tried to add a basemap through the Insert tab > New Map > Basemap, but all I get then is a blank page.

I found two Basemap troubleshooting guides and, while they are both for ArcMap too, I have followed the steps as good as possible (including changes to the ESRI folder in AppData and the registry), but to no avail.

I have a solid internet connection, switching off anti-virus and Firewall didn't help.
I have added trusted websites, and I have an active protal.

I have also tried the two posts I found on this forum, but still nothing.

Comment: This seems to be on your instructor to work out. Following ArcMap procedures exactly is not going to work in Pro. Having not provided any links, nor detailing your exact procedure,  it's less likely we can help either.

Comment: Have you logged into pro?

Comment: I have logged in using a free arc-online account. I don't have a paid one.

Comment: Sorry Vince, you're absolutely right.

Comment: Sorry Vince, you're absolutely right. I've used these links: 
https://community.esri.com/t5/esri-technical-support-blog/troubleshooting-issues-adding-arcgis-online/ba-p/900112
And this one:
https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013300
On Stackaxchange these:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116956/add-basemap-grayed-out-in-arcmap
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332498/add-basemap-showing-blank-window